# Symfony "Unknown knp_menu_render function" on production

Tags: symfony, knpmenu

When transfering to production server I've got this error.

```
[2016-04-27 18:45:23] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-04-27 18:45:24] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown "knp_menu_render" function in "dailyShop/index.html.twig" at line 210." at /home/ashkov/www/ruproms.ru/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php line 573 {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Syntax(code: 0): Unknown \"knp_menu_render\" function in \"dailyShop/index.html.twig\" at line 210. at /home/ashkov/www/ruproms.ru/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:573)"} []
```

In the development enviroment everything is ok.

**composer update** was made several times.

**new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle()**, on its place in app/AppKernel.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

```
php bin/console cache:clear -e prod
```